# Taxonomy term view page for  terms with same name but with different term id?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views, path-aliases

I have several taxonomy terms that have the same name but different term id in a same hierarchical taxonomy vocabularies. I would like to display them in the same term view page.

Example:

```
-line-1       (tid=1)
   -station-1 (tid=2)
   -station-2 (tid=3)
   -station-3 (tid=4)
-line-2       (tid=5)
   -station-3 (tid=6)
   -station-4 (tid=7)
   -station-5 (tid=8)
```

`station-3` of `line-1` and `station-3` of `line-1` have the same name "station-3" but they have different term id.

What I would like to do is to have just one term view page with one path that displays nodes tagged with both `station-3` of `line-1` and `station-3` of `line-1`. but not separate two term pages like `/taxonomy/term/4` and `/taxonomy/term/6`

Is there anyway to do this?
And please feel free to change the title if it is not appropriate.